# Win10 Wifi securty too strict to watch EagleCam site ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, security, wifi-configuration

I want to watch an eagle Live Camera site dickpritchettrealestate.com it always gives the error message ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE.

- Using Chrome
- Using Win10
- Using Wifi
- Using built in Windows firewall
- Using built  in Windows antivirus/malware
- Successfully and properly connected to the Internet.
- I can view the site properly on my mobile phone.
- I have cleared the ip addresses
- I have cleared web history, cache, cookies, etc.
- I have flushed dns.

On my PC I can view many web pages fine. Only certain webpages with small programs on it do not work. Live camera sites, and pages to pay bills online e.g. ATT do not work. I can use Youtube without any problems. The same problem occurs when other web browsers; Edge, Firefox, Chrome.

When I connect to the Internet with a wired ethernet cable I can see all websites without any problems. What settings in Wifi do I change to view all websites?

EDIT: this so so I can primarily pay bills online, the livecam site was just a easy to give example without involving personal information or signing up to the actual webpage.

Comment: Why don’t you just watch the video directly on YouTube, that’s the only video, on that website. Why do you want to watch the YouTube video on the website instead of on YouTube? This is likely a DNS issue that only surfaces with AT&T DNS servers

Comment: It takes some time, but I have no problem seeing the videos. Also, if I right-click the video and select "Copy video URL" I get a YouTube URL that I can watch live (but nothing much is happening...)

Comment: This also occurs on other sites like ATT Pay My Bill. I pay most of my bills online. I am only using the livecam site as a basic "no login test" location.